# Canadian English Keyboard Layout?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I recently installed Elementary OS on my computer and for some reason Canadian English is not on the list of available keyboard layouts, which is weird since I can see Nigerian, Ghanaian, and Cameroonian English there. There's Canadian French, but no Canadian English. I'm currently using British English as it's closer than American English in spelling, but it's still not perfect. Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to System Settings -> Keyboard

```
$ io.elementary.switchboard keyboard
```

---

Press the + (plus) button to add a new one

[image]

---

Select `French (Canada)`

[image]

---

Select `English (Canada)` variant

[image]

---

### Github

I wrote a report on this, it needs a redesign

https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-keyboard/issues/201

Answer (score 6):

What version of elementary OS you are using?

Please try selecting your Language to `French(Canada)` and then select layout `English(Canada)` from Layout setting under Keyboard.